# How to compile this qt program(There is no any pro file)?

Tags: qt, qt4, qml, qt-quick, qt3d

I download the code(a game made with qt 3d) from [Qt learning websites](http://download.qt-project.org/learning/developerguides/gamedevelopmentqt3d/)

After decompressing it, all i found are some qml file and photos. There is no any c++ file or the pro file. How can i open this as a project not a file in the qt creator and run it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not contain any source code, just qml files. It is entirely written in interpreted QML. You would need to run the "main.qml", which is the "game.qml" here, through the qml viewer as follows:

```
qmlviewer-qt4 game.qml
```

or

```
qmlviewer-qt4 game.qml
```

These applications are installed by the qt/qtquick and qtquick1 packages on my Linux box.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.But it show this `module "Qt3D" is not installed` after i type that command. My use qt5.3, and it says that `Qt5 is the first Qt version where Qt3D is available
as an Essential Module`. So, I am confused and can not continue. How to install that missed module?

Comment: @Ziu: obviously, you need to install qt3d. No, qt3d is not available off-hand in 5.3.0.

Comment: @Ziu: I think you might have more luck with Qt 4 and Qt3D.

Comment: Sorry for answering you so late. My network doesn't work right with stackoverflow, hardly get here. I get some problem at installing `qt3d`. Especially my network would block many website, so it is very inconvenient to get some useful information. But anyway, really thanks for you help.